# Is there any way to apply CSS for specific Chrome version?

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, compatibility

I'm facing a problem in **Chrome version 59 alone**. I need a CSS solution to target that chrome version. I saw an article with this example code says its working, but in my case it doesn't work.

**example 1**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .logotext-n {
        .chrome59.margin-left: -10px; /* update for Chrome 59 issue */
     } 
}
```

**example 2**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
  .chrome59.logotext-n {
      margin-left: -10px; /* update for Chrome 59 issue */
  } 
}
```

both the examples doesn't work.

Comment: jQuerry or javascript aren't an option ?

Comment: @Doomenik no way in css ?

Comment: if you could tell us what exactly is your problem we could help you more rather giving you css hack

Comment: I've a problem with the **property - position:fixed** in Chrome version 59 alone... it's not working fine in that specific version...

Comment: @AjaiKrishnanR There is one within html. With the <if> tag but I forgot how the syntax for Chrome versions was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should in principle always design for feature detection, not browser detection.

If your page renders differently in different browsers, make sure that your [markup](https://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) are valid.

When all else fails, you may need to detect a browser and even a specific version of that browser. As far as I know, there is no CSS hack that can be used to detect version 59 of Google Chrome specifically. In general, it is very hard to find such hacks for specific versions of specific browsers.

It is possible to detect using JavaScript, and this can also be used to inject styles into the DOM.

```js
function isChrome59() {
  var test = navigator.userAgent.match(/chrom(?:e|ium)\/(\d+)\./i);
  if (test) {
    return (parseInt(test[1], 10) === 59);
  }
  return false;
}

if (isChrome59()) {
  var styles = document.createElement('style');
  styles.textContent = 'p { color: red; }';
  document.head.appendChild(styles);
}
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>This text will be blue in all browsers, except in version 59 of Google Chrome, where it will be colored red.</p>
```

The above example loads inline styles, but you can of course also create a separate stylesheet and insert a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />` to reference it.

Answer (score -2):

A java script answer (where you can target all builds of chrome) is java script and use something like

```
function getChromeVersion () {     
    var element = document.querySelectorAll(.logotext-n)[0];

if (getChromeVersion() == 59) class.style.chrome59.margin-left = -10 + 'px'
}
```

Comment: is this for Chrome ?

Comment: Don't get it. What IE has to do with Chrome?

Comment: Yes its for chrome, please check answer