# why position:fixed is not working in Chrome version 59?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, browser, compatibility

**position:fixed** is not working in **Chrome version 59**..
I've a toolbar in my application it is fixed below the menubar in the app. It's working fine in all other browser including Chrome with this below CSS rule, except Chrome version 59. Is there any way to fix this issue with **CSS or jQuery ?**

```
#toolBar {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    height: 29px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3d5fa3;
    left: 19.4%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999999999999999;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Chrome version 59 alone misbehaves whit this.
another question regarding the same : [Is there any way to apply CSS for specific chrome version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008896/is-there-any-way-to-apply-css-for-specific-chrome-version?noredirect=1#comment76991940_45008896)

Comment: Can you give us some HTML too, so we can see it not working. Thanks.

Comment: maybe it hidden in bottom, try add `top: 0`

Comment: @uingtea Top is not required, It's 'coz of perception lag, it needs **transform: translateZ(0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome.. this simple line solved my entire problem.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

position:fixed* issue, adding this line to my CSS rule fixed all my issues, working fine... fix for chrome 59 and above... :)

Thanks all, for your efforts.