# CSS only for newer Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

is there any way to do CSS only for Chrome 49 and below? My browser is chrome 60, when I print a huge table, it display normally (page break very smooth), but when I try to print use Chrome 49, it display very bad, there's no page break (thead not displaying again when change page). I can't update my client browser because he currently use XP, and Chrome version that available only in XP is Chrome 49. Is there any solution?

I already tried to change css for chrome 49, it really smooth.. but when I change to my computer (chrome 60) then it goes bad... So i need at least 1 condition to determines chrome version, so I can activate my CSS only on chrome 49

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008896/is-there-any-way-to-apply-css-for-specific-chrome-version oh and here some css hacks not exactly for your case but yeah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328832/how-to-apply-specific-css-rules-to-chrome-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to apply CSS for specific chrome version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008896/is-there-any-way-to-apply-css-for-specific-chrome-version)

Comment: Chrome v60 might be great but you shouldn't write for a single version. As to OP try to markup logical table header with `display:table-header-row`. There is no crucial CSS difference between Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

Comment: Just see this answer of [Just a student](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011149) and change the number from `59` to `49`.

Comment: @Doomenik perfect! that second link very useful... I found that first link but didn't work, but your second link about using JS is awesome... thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900436/how-to-detect-the-installed-chrome-version